# Fixed div left of centered div

Tags: css, layout, html

I can't for the life of me get this to work. I want a fixed div (menu) to the left of a centered div (content). The page should be able to resize as usual with the fixed div touching the left window wall when the window get smaller.

I made a drawing of what I want to do:

[Image of what I want to accomplish](http://postimage.org/image/swy7lic8l/)

**EDIT** I want to be able to resize the window and the content and menu should not fall out from the left browser wall. And also the Menu should always be fixed relative to the content... **EDIT**

**EDIT2** The following did exactly what I wanted (expanded solution from xFortyFourx):

```
#body{width: 1200px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 0 auto;}
#wrap {width: 800px;min-width: 800px;min-height: 1800px;margin: 0px auto;border: 2px #000 solid;position: relative;}
#sidebar {width: 160px;height: 100px; border: 2px #000 solid;position: absolute;top: 0;left: -180px;}
#fixed{position: fixed; width: 160px; height: 50px; background-color: #234324;}
<div id="body"><div id="wrap"><p>Content</p><div id="sidebar"><div id="fixed"><p>Sidebar</p></div></div></div></div>
```

**EDIT2**

Comment: What browsers do you want to support? Is html5 + css3 an option? Or *shudder* do you need to support IE6?

Comment: @Zapmore It would be nice if you post what have you tried so far

Comment: IE 7 and up would be nice (since people still use older browsers). No need for ie6 tho...

Comment: I tried a lot of things while looking at other websites, but my closest thing is to have a main body div 100%. Then center the content div with "auto" inside of the body. And then try to play around with the menu div with different margins... (inside the meny div is a div with fixed content so it always stay fixed even when scrolling.)

Comment: When you say "fixed", do you mean `position: fixed`?

Comment: @thirtydot Kinda, just said fixed since people maybe have a better way of doing this and I didn't want to limit their suggestion with "position:fixed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="sidebar"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#wrap {
    width: 950px;
    min-height: 400px;

    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 2px #000 solid;

    position: relative;
}
    #sidebar {
        width: 50px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 2px #000 solid;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: -70px;
    }
```

Edit : here's a sample http://jsfiddle.net/XWkBw/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is exactly what I want to acconmplish, works great when I put a fixed div inside of the sidebar as a navigation :) However is it possible to protect if the browser is resized smaller that the sidebar don't fall out from the window to the left if you know what I mean. 

If I make the browser window smaller, that the sidebar div will be touching the left browser wall and not surpass is (could be dangerous since it is the navigation for the webpage...)

Comment: "Yes, you can add all your contents inside <div id="wrap"> </div>, just leave the sidebar div at the end. –" But when I make the window smaller, the "#sidebar" disappears out on the left and that is a big problem since it is the navigation for the site. The "#wrap" stays within the window like it should...

Comment: @Zapmore , to keep things simple and not to involve Javascript, you can give your container div a "min-width: 100px;" [ the container in the above example is "wrap" ].

Comment: and like @Murtaza suggested, you may use "position: fixed" for "sidebar" if you want it to stay on the page even while scrolling.

Comment: I expanded on what you have done and I came to the following conclusion  that does exactly what I want. 

(see edit in main question)

Comment: @Zapmore I guess "#body" is a div with id = "body" and not meant for the <body> tag. If you assigned it to body tag, please create an extra div. It's not good practice to constrict the body tag.

Comment: yea exactly, its a separate div and not the <body> tag. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="navigation">
        nav    
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        content        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;        
}

.navigation {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.content {
    margin-left : 110px;
}
```

jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZUrF/

Comment: Thank you for the advice, however this is not what I want to accomplish. I want the content to be centered and the navigation to be left of the centered content...

Comment: Yes, you can add all your contents inside <div id="wrap"> </div>, just leave the sidebar div at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you can go through this example:

[Fixed Box on left hand side](http://jsfiddle.net/XWkBw/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="sidebar"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;

    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 2px #000 solid;

    position: relative;
}
    #sidebar {
        width: 50px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 2px #000 solid;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        left: 60px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem with the sidebar fall out from the left browser window when resize, but the sidbar doesn't stay fixed nexxt to the content, the sidebar should be a navigation meny...